# What is the purpose of using TokenValidationParameters?

Tags: c#, security, asp.net-web-api

I'm stepping through some code for an existing application and it reads a local cert. Why would an application do this? What type of security does this provide? How can I generate a new cert for a new application?

```
            var local = ReadLocalCertificate();

            tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                                        {
                                            ValidAudience = appSettings.IdamClientId,
                                            ValidIssuer = appSettings.IdamIssuer,
                                            IssuerSigningKey =
                                                new X509SecurityKey(local)
                                        };
```

Comment: What do you mean "why would an application do this"? Why would it have options?

Comment: I just want to know the benefit of doing this and how I can learn more about what the purpose is.

Comment: One thing is that, in a microservice world, the service that validates the token signature doesn't have to be the same service as the one that validates the rest of the token. A flow might involve a reverse proxy first asking an auth service to verify that the token is legit, and then the proxy would make a subsequent call to the actual API endpoint. The auth service might only care about the signature, not the audience/issuer, and the api endpoint wouldn't check the signature, but might check the audience/issuer.